# NSArrayController - add: & remove: programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, action, nsmutabledictionary, nsarraycontroller

I know this is an easy one, but I just thought I could spare myself some (more) time searching through the documentation.

Usually, when I have an "Add" and a "Remove" button, along with an `NSArrayController`, I simply have to click-drag from each button and connect them to the `add:` and `remove:` actions of the `NSArrayController`.

Now, I'm trying to do the very same thing, programmatically with `NSArrayController` (`co`) :

```
[addButton setAction:@selector(add:)];
[addButton setTarget:co];
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

*The rest of the `NSArrayController` operations, handling an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries, etc works fine.*

Comment: Well, what's going wrong? The code you posted is correct, so you're going to need to help us help you diagnose the problem by giving more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugger* tells me that you're probably doing this in an `init` method, where neither of the outlets, to the array controller or the button, are connected yet.

Put this into `awakeFromNib` or a method which you know is called *after* the xib is loaded.

---

*`psydb`, of course.

Comment: Hmmm... Unfortunately, everything is connected and nope,it's not the `init` method either...

Comment: You're sure that `co` and  `addButton:` are not `nil` at this point? Then please do as Itai asked and add more information -- what is actually happening?